# Confusion reading a passage in JPA Mini Book

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I have read in [JPA Mini Book](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/java/naited/JPA_Mini_Book.pdf), this passage:

> "allocationSize = 53" represents the amount of ids that JPA will store
>   in cache. Works like this: when the application is started JPA will
>   allocate in memory the specified number of ids and will share these
>   values to each new persisted entity. In the code above, the ids would
>   go from 10 (initialValue) up to 63 (initialValue + allocationSize).
>   When the number of allocated ids ends JPA will request from the
>   database and allocate in memory 53 more ids. This act of allocating
>   ids into memory is a good approach to optimize server memory, since
>   JPA will not need to trigger the database with every insert so as to
>   get the created id just like with the @Identity approach.

Questions:

1. After reading `when the application is started JPA will allocate in memory the specified number of ids..`, I had a reflex, they talk about which JPA? the JPA of `NetBeans` or `glassfish`? does the EAR contain JPA?
2. In this sentence `When the number of allocated ids ends JPA will request from the database and allocate in memory 53 more ids`, what will JPA request from the database?
3. Here they say `since JPA will not need to trigger the database with every insert so as to get the created id just like with the @Identity approach`, does using `IDENTITY` means JPA will not use `CACHE` and using `SEQUENCE` means that JPA will use `CACHE`? doesn't using such a strategy (SEQUENCE) means that we have a risk of consistency in our data? Suppose that we want to update 20 rows so JPA will not call the DB yet, and another user is updating the same rows seeing the old data, doesn't this a problem? what am I missing? please explain this to me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1- This is JPA specification that any provider has to stick to it, hibernate or eclipse link or any other jpa implementation (I don't know those that you mentioned)

2- We have for ways to auto generate entity id (corresponding to table primary key) while inserting, 1 - AUTO : which means auto increment, 2 - SEQUENCE_GENERATOR : which uses a DB sequence .next() , 3 - TABLE_GENERATOR : similar to sequence, but uses a table with 2 columns, one is the entity name (or a corresponding name) and the other is max id value, 4- IDENTITY : which uses a table property present in some databases called identifier columns .... now back to your question, when you insert a new record using allocationSize = 53 and using sequence or table generator then the value in the value in the sequence or the table will be incremented with this value 53 (thus becomes 63) and the jpa will then be able to insert entities with ids 10 -> 63 without hitting the DB again

3- concerning your consistency question , all the topic is about inserting new rows not updating and concerning IDENTITY , allocation size is only for sequence and table generators, so in case of IDENTIITY , no caching is there

Comment: for 1- it seems that you didn't understand my question, for 2- I can't understand what you wrote and for 3- can you provide a link to backup your says

Comment: 1- can u explain more
2- I edited the answer , please check again
3- refer to Pro JPA 2 or the JPA specs